# How to stop the ticker once turtles run out of "wealth" in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

> **> Hi, I'm new to NetLogo and this is my 1st model. Basically, I would
>
> > like the 'ticker' to stoprunning once the turtles have spent their
> > 'wealth'. I have tried looking through the various models if I can copy/adapt some of the codes but to no avail. Appreciate any help that
> > I can get. Thanks**

```
turtles-own [wealth]
patches-own [income]

to setup
  ca
  setup-turtles
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks

end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 1000
  ask turtles
  [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set wealth 100
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of 4000 patches [ set pcolor green ]
end


to go
  move-turtles
  spend
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
   ifelse wealth > 0
    [rt random 360 forward 1]
    [stop]

  ]
end


to spend
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = green [
      set wealth wealth - 1
      set income income + 1
    ]
   ]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to NetLogo.  `stop` is a funny command that does different things in different places.  In particular, it does not stop the simulation unless it is called within or directly from the `go` procedure.  If it did stop the model from the place where you have put it, it would do so when the first turtle achieved zero wealth and, I assume, you want the model to stop only when all turtles have zero wealth.  I would suggest modifying the model as follows:

```
to go
  if not any? turtles with [wealth > 0] [stop]
  move-turtles
  spend
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
    if wealth > 0
    [rt random 360 forward 1]
  ]
end
    
to spend
  ask turtles with [wealth > 0] [
    if pcolor = green [
      set wealth wealth - 1
      set income income + 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

The `go` procedure now checks for the stopping condition at the end of each tick.  I've also added a line to `spend` that prevents wealth from going negative for turtles on green patches, although perhaps negative wealth might have some meaning for you.  If so, you can just take that line out.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thank you so much for this! This is exactly what I was looking for. You even addressed the negative wealth part!.

Comment: Hi Charles, one more thing, how do I set up monitors for a certain range? ie I'm looking to monitor the total income in a green patch in several categories. ie those patch that has a wealth between 1-100, between 101 to 200, between 201 to 300, above 300 and no income.